# How can I reset a Vector3 position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to write a script that instantiates a row of prefabs. This worked the first time, but every time after that it instantiates one at 0x,0y,0z and the rest ~30x-40x away. I tried setting the initial position before the for loop executes and then resetting the position using the initalPos variable, but that doesn't seem to work. in my code

```
    public class generator : MonoBehaviour {

    public int height = 0;
    public int width = 0;
    private Vector3 temp;
    public GameObject sprite;
    private Vector3 initialPos;


    void Start () 
    {
        initialPos = new Vector3(0,0,0);

        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            Instantiate (sprite, temp, Quaternion.identity);
            temp = sprite.transform.position;
            temp.x += 0.089f;
            sprite.transform.position = temp;
        }
        temp = initialPos;
    }
}
```

The temp variable is what I'm setting the current position to so I can add 0.089 to it so that my sprites will line up. I'm trying to reset that value so that they line up starting at 0x every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code by specifying the number of prefabs you wish to spawn in a row, rather than the exact width.

Additionally, instead of incrementing your spawn position x value by a hard coded number, use `gameObject.transform.localScale.x` instead.

For example:

```
public GameObject Cube;

void Start()
{
    SpawnRow(Vector3.zero, 10);
}

void SpawnRow(Vector3 startPosition, int RowLength)
{
    Vector3 currentPos = startPosition;

    for (int i = 0; i < RowLength; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(Cube, currentPos, Quaternion.identity);
        currentPos.x += Cube.transform.localScale.x;
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you wanted to do something like spawn additional rows next to your each other, you could call SpawnRow() like this:

```
void Start()
{
    Vector3 currentPos = Vector3.zero;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        SpawnRow(currentPos, 10);
        currentPos.z += Cube.transform.localScale.z;
    }
}
```

This would give you three rows of 10 gameObjects directly next to each other.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware of localScale OR Vector3.zero. Fixed my issues and taught me a couple things. I really appreciate it.